# Error: 'g++' could not be spawned. Is it installed and on your path?

Tags: gcc, g++, atom-editor

While trying to run c++ in Atom editor.

I installed 'gpp compiler' in Atom Editor File==>Settings==>Packages==>'gpp-compiler'
I also installed `gcc-core-9.2.0-1-mingw32-bin` and provided it's \bin path in PATH variable.
Still I am getting this error while running a simple C++ code.
[image]

> Error: 'g++' could not be spawned. Is it installed and on your path?

Any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. In Atom editor install gpp-compiler. File==>Settings==>Packages==>Search 'gpp-compiler' ==> Install.
2. Go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/ and download migw-get-setup.exe. Install it by running and selecting all executables.
   [image]
3. By default MingW is installed in C:\MingW. Set PATH in env variable "C:\MingW\bin" or where the binary installed.
4. Verify if g++ installed, by running `g++ --version` in your command terminal.
5. Now, open your Atom editor as 'Run as Administrator' and create a hello world cpp file and Right click on it ==> 'Compile and Run'

Done!!

Comment: `Run as Administrator` - why?

Comment: @MariuszJaskółka: It's been long time since I wrote this answer.
You can try without 'Run as Administrator'.